# At most, how many elements does a binary search examine if the array contains 100 elements?

Tags: java, binary-search

Wouldn't it be half of the elements for arrays of even length but what would happen for arrays of odd length?

Comment: No, it's not half. Put on paper different cases and check. Start with 10 and you'll understand.

Comment: You should try to trace it by hand :)

Comment: Try to understand the algo before making any implications about the algorithm. Just a hint: take a look at the runtime-complexity

Comment: It examines up to *log2(n)* elements. In your case, that rounds to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an average it examines logn elements. At most it will examine logn +1 elements.

Comment: I get it now. Got the concepts mixed up with the binary search function that eliminates half of an array. Also why would you +1 to log2(n)?

Comment: @Strategiger What is the worst possible outcome if you used binary search on array of 2 elements?